# How do I check if multiple elements of a list are equal to a variable?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a shuffled playing card deck and in order to do so I have to check if the generated card is equal to the previous ones. So far I have tried this:

```
for i in range(51):
a=card()
while(deck[:i]==a):
    a=card()
deck[i]=a
```

card is the function that generates a random card
I think that the problem is in the [:i]
P.S. The list already has 52 elements and they are all set as "Empty"

Comment: Why not build a list of all cards, then call `random.shuffle` on the list representing the deck?

Comment: So I create the list using two while loops (one for numbers and one for suits) and then how do I use random.shuffle?

Comment: Once you have a list of everything, let's say you called it `deck`, just use `random.shuffle(deck)`. You can look at the docs for that too here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, you can do something like this:

```
for i in range(51):
    a = card()
    while a in deck:
        a = card()
    deck[i] = a
```

You can test for membership using `a in deck` because you said that deck is initialized to empty, so you don't have to check up to the i'th element, as the elements after i definitely won't contain a.

However, there is a better way to create a shuffled deck of cards: use `random.shuffle` as ctj232 said.

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[3, 5, 4, 2, 1]
```

Make a list that represents all 52 cards in order, making your own class or just integers, then use the `random` library to shuffle them.

Comment: This solves the same problem OP is facing but doesn't answer his particular question. At the very least answer the question and offer the alternative afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
    import random

    cards = [  i for i in range(52)]
    curentPosition = [  i for i in range(52)]
    nextPosition = [  i for i in range(52)]

    print('Positions before shufle:\n',curentPosition)

    for i in cards:
        randomPos = random.choice(nextPosition)
        curentPosition[i] = randomPos
        nextPosition.remove(randomPos)


    print('Positions after shufle\n',curentPosition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `random.shuffle` is absolutely the best way to solve your issue as the other answer has explained, but to answer your original question:

To check if multiple elements of a list are equal to a variable, you can use the `variable in list` syntax:

```
my_list = [51,47,2,29,6]
if 51 in my_list:
    print("51 is already selected")
else:
    print("51 isn't in my_list")
```

To apply this to your existing code:

```
for i in range(51):
    a=card()
    while(a in deck):
        a=card()
    deck[i]=a
```